# Server sent events stopped work after enabling ssl on proxy

Tags: ssl, nginx, server-sent-events

I made web project, that based on Tomcat and Nginx in front of him. 
Had to work hard to make it work without errors.
However, when I added ssl to nginx. Stopped working server sent events.
If i acess to backend server directly - it works, so problem somewhere whith nginx.
Have someone with such a problem?
Here is relative parts of configuration

My nginx.conf (im not using sites-enabled yet, and placed my app configured here too. Basic settings at the end of conf). /SecurConfig/api/tutorial/listen - is source of events

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
worker_connections 768;
# multi_accept on;
}

http {

root /data/;

server{
listen 80;
#   server_name ajaxdemo.in.ua;
#   proxy_set_header Host ajaxdemo.in.ua;
location / {
rewrite ^(.*)$ https://ajaxdemo.in.ua$1 permanent;
}
}

server {
#listen 80;
listen 443 default ssl;

#ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key; 



  proxy_set_header  Host               $host;
  proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header            X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

location / {
    root /data/www;

    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' *;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET';

    if ($http_cookie ~* "jsessionid=([^;]+)(?:;|$)") {
        set $co "jsessionid=$1";
        }
    #proxy_set_header Cookie "$co";

    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1666/SecurConfig/;
    #proxy_pass http://88.81.229.142:1666/SecurConfig/;
    add_before_body /header.html;
    add_after_body /footer.html;
}


location /SecurConfig/api/tutorial/listen {

    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' *;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET';

    ##Server sent events set
    proxy_set_header Connection '';
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    chunked_transfer_encoding off;

    proxy_connect_timeout 300;
   proxy_send_timeout 300;
   proxy_read_timeout 300;

    proxy_buffering on;
    proxy_buffer_size 8k;
    #proxy_cache off;
    ##


    if ($http_cookie ~* "jsessionid=([^;]+)(?:;|$)") {
        set $co "jsessionid=$1";
        }
    #proxy_set_header Cookie "$co";
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1666/;
    #proxy_pass http://88.81.229.142:1666/;

}


location /SecurConfig/ {
    root /data/www;

    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' *;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET';

    if ($http_cookie ~* "jsessionid=([^;]+)(?:;|$)") {
        set $co "jsessionid=$1";
        }
    #proxy_set_header Cookie "$co";

    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1666/;
    #proxy_pass http://88.81.229.142:1666/;
    add_before_body /header.html;
    add_after_body /footer.html;
}

location ~ \.css$ {
root /data/css/;
}

location /header.html {
root  /data/www;
}
location /footer.html {
root  /data/www;
}

location ~ \.(gif|jpg|png|jpeg)$ {
    root /data/images;
}

}


##
# Basic Settings
##

sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
keepalive_timeout 65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
client_max_body_size 100m;

include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;

##
# Logging Settings
##

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

##
# Gzip Settings
##

gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";


##
# Virtual Host Configs
##

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
#   include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

There are no error entries in error logs of nginx.
But there is also mention about acess to /SecurConfig/api/tutorial/listen in acess logs. Code 200 means "all is ok"

> "GET /SecurConfig/api/tutorial/listen HTTP/1.1" 200 187 "https://ajaxdemo.in.ua/SecurConfig/api/tutorial/map/11111111" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0"

Tomcat log shows acess to /SecurConfig/api/tutorial/listen as usual(e.g. checks security acess, accepts it, and resends to controller).
If i run my page in chrome developer mode, i see this error

```
GET https://ajaxdemo.in.ua/SecurConfig/api/tutorial/listen net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

#### UPD

Okay. While i searched info on internet, i left my page with SSE opened. And after 10 minutes, i saw, that my data appeared just as it must be. I commented all settings according to buffering

> ```
>     #proxy_buffering on;
>     #proxy_buffer_size 8k;
>     #proxy_cache off;
> ```

And i commented also parameters

> ```
>      #proxy_connect_timeout 300;
>     #proxy_send_timeout 300;
>     #proxy_read_timeout 300;
> ```

So this parameters returned top its default (about 20 sec)
And all my data appeared after ~20 sec.
So i setted

> ```
>   proxy_connect_timeout 2;
>     proxy_send_timeout 2;
>     proxy_read_timeout 2;
> ```

And data appeared faster. But its.s still in one piece(3-4 events at once), before enabling ssl events showed one by one.
Still ned your help, and explanation, where i was wrong.

#### UPD

Here is conhiguration from my server, when i "turn off" ssl and SSE works.
[ssl is off - sse works](http://pastebin.com/EWQ5Svzu)
[80 port redirecting to 443 ssl - sse not works](http://pastebin.com/TkeB6L6e)

Comment: Is there any auth or cookies required? And are you sure you are not hitting any CORS restrictions when you moved to using SSL? (http and https count as distinct origins) (Also make sure you've tested in both Chrome and Firefox, as I remember hitting browsers bugs in this area.)
The other thing I wondered about was why proxy_buffering is on in the SSE section of your config.
If any of those guesses helps, let me know and I'll post a proper answer :-)

Comment: 1)Yes. Cookies are required for session security check on tomcat side. And it checks cookie sucesfully. 2) "add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' *;" - this should protect me from cross domain origins. And as for http/https - i dont know how to check if there is issue. 3)Yep, i checked both on chrome and firefox. 4)proxy_buffering must protect me from "shredding" messages. If buffering if "off" then nginx can cut long messages apart. It worked before enabling ssl anyway.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For SSE to work properly, you must make sure nothing is getting cached or buffered: not in your script (e.g. in PHP we have the `@ob_flush();@flush()` idiom), not at your web server, and not at any intermediate proxies or firewalls.

You say you commented out all the nginx commands to do with buffering, but commenting out means it will use the defaults. E.g. the default for `proxy_buffering` is `on`. I would suggest explictly specifying them to make sure all buffering and caching is switched off.

```
proxy_buffering off;
proxy_buffer_size 0;
proxy_cache off;
```

I would also consider explicitly setting the timeouts high, rather than commenting them out. The definition of "high" depends on your application. E.g. if it is always sending data every couple of seconds, the defaults will be fine. But if you are using SSE for irregular data, and there might sometimes be half an hour between messages, make sure the timeouts are more than half an hour.

**UPDATE:** Apparently (see the comments) adding `response.addHeader("X-Accel-Buffering", "no");` (i.e. to the server-side process, not to the proxy config) fixes the problem. This makes sense, as that was added specifically for SSE and similar HTTP streaming, see the [nginx documentation](http://wiki.nginx.org/X-accel#X-Accel-Buffering). It does imply the above Nginx configuration should also work (the OP has reported that it does not). But, on the other hand, using a header to disable buffering on a per-connection basis feels like a better solution anyway.

Comment: It seems logical. But disabling buffers did not help. At least in the form in which you suggested. Still need to experiment. I suppose, that my data just flushes after closing listen source if i set low timeouts. Somewhere buffer is still on...

Comment: Okay, i solved problem, by adding manually header "response.addHeader("X-Accel-Buffering", "no");". So even if there is some bufer is still on - nginx will not use it for processing packets with this header.
@Darren Cook could you update your answer with this info? So i can accept it.

Comment: @Asprelis I think you could self-answer? (or does that need a minimum rep?) I'm still confused though, as according to http://wiki.nginx.org/X-accel#X-Accel-Buffering that command just switches of proxy buffering on one connection. Isn't it just an alternative to `proxy_buffering off;` I wonder if the latter is in the wrong place in your nginx config file (or something along those lines)??

Comment: Your post contains more useful information. I would like other people read it too. So please update your post.

Comment: @Asprelis OK, done. By the way, was this extra header definitely only needed with SSL, and not needed when using the proxy server but with http? (If true, that bothers me, as it means something I don't understand is happening beneath the surface.)

Comment: Ok, thanx. I will update my question in order to show you configurations with and / without ssl. Unfortunately, my expertise not enough to see where is critical difference.

Comment: Thank you for that update, you are a life saver. For the record, adding that header to my app was all I needed to do after adding my SSL certificate.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: this was my answer before the OP gathered more information (in particular that if he waited long enough the data arrived, i.e. that it was a buffering issue: see my other answer). I've decided to leave it here as it might be useful troubleshooting ideas for someone else. (But if you disagree leave a comment or flag for deleting.)

---

When planning "Data Push Apps with HTML5 SSE", using proxy servers was unfortunately the other side of where we drew the line; if you've read chapter 9 you'll know a seemingly simple standard can still get very complicated. So, I'm very interested to hear if and how you get this working.

The first thing that comes to mind is you are using self-signed SSL certs. They won't work with SSE with Chrome. Ajax won't either. (See [the bug report](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=96007), but it was opened in 2011, so don't hold your breath.) However you said it works with Firefox, so this is unlikely to be it.

The next thought is that you are using `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*`, and `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true`, so I assume that means you need to for CORS (I.e. your html page origin and your SSE script origin are different in some way), and that cookies are involved.  Are you setting `{ withCredentials: true }` as the 2nd parameter to your `EventSource` constructor in your JavaScript? Even if so, be aware that `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true` does not work with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*`. You cannot specify `*`, and instead you have to explicitly say which origin is allowed.

If that is the problem, you can use your server-side script to make the header dynamically, based on the client's origin. (The book shows code to do this in PHP.) If nginx can use environmental variables from the user's request, you should be able to do it there too.

However, my understanding was that this would trip up with http too. I don't think it should just be an https problem. (If I'm wrong on that, let me know.)

(Oh, if your working http SSE requests were coming from http://example.com, and are still coming from http://example.com, even though the SSE request is now going to https://example.com, then everything makes sense - you did not get CORS failures before because the origin was the same; now you do have a CORS problem, and you are not handling it correctly.)

My third guess, is that the browser is sending a preflight OPTIONS request, but only doing it with https requests. (Preflight requests wildly from browser to browser, but it is not impossible that current versions of Chrome and Firefox behave the same way.) When you get an OPTIONS request you need to send back `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Last-Event-ID, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization`. You also need to send back the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` header.

You can confirm or refute this third guess by packet sniffing to see what exactly is being sent back and forth. And if all the above ideas turned up nothing, you should do that anyway.

Comment: wow, i newer thought that sse is so complicated. I realy use self-signed ssl sertificate. Ill try to investigate your guesses.

Comment: Wow. While i searched info in internet, and left my application page open - after some long time i received my data, axactly as it should be. But with huge delay. I did'n change nothing yet.

Answer (score 1):

Briefly, nginx detects if connection is alive with backend application and  detection may not work correct in case of SSL, as described here

http://mailman.nginx.org/pipermail/nginx/2013-March/038120.html