# Server-Sent Events with Next.js 14 on Vercel: Task timed out after 15.00 seconds

Tags: next.js, vercel, server-sent-events, next.js14

I developing an application that uses Server-Side Events (SSE) to stream a Twitch Account Name to a display screen to change / display a Twitch embed.The application works locally but when i deploy it to Vercel I get the error:

`Task timed out after 15.01 seconds`

The client is also unable to reconnect and the error message just keeps on going.

Here is a snippet of my code:
Route.ts

```
export async function GET() {
  const encoder = new TextEncoder();
  let screenId: string;

  const cookieStore = cookies();
  const TokenCookie = cookieStore.get("Token");

  if (!TokenCookie) {
    return new Response("Token not found", { status: 401 });
  }

  try {
    const Token = await verify(TokenCookie.value);
    const TokenPayload = JSON.parse(Token.payload as string);

    screenId = TokenPayload.id;
    console.log("Token ID:", screenId);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error verifying token:", error);
    return new Response("Invalid token", { status: 403 });
  }
  
  const customReadable = new ReadableStream({
    async start(controller) {
      redisSubscriber.subscribe(setKey, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error("Error subscribing to Redis:", err);
          controller.error(err); // Signal an error in the stream
          return;
        }
      });

      redisSubscriber.on("message", (channel, message) => {

        const parsed = JSON.parse(message);
        if (channel === setKey && parsed.screenId === screenId) {
          controller.enqueue(encoder.encode(`data: ${message}\n\n`));
        } else {
          console.log("Invalid token, ignoring message.");
        }
      });

      redisSubscriber.on("error", (error) => {
        console.error("Redis error:", error);
        controller.error(error); 
      });
    }

  });

  return new Response(customReadable, {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "text/event-stream; charset=utf-8",
      "Connection": "keep-alive",
      "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
      "Content-Encoding": "none",
    },
  });
}
```

page.tsx

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let eventSource = new EventSource("/api/stream");

    eventSource.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
      try {
        const streamData = JSON.parse(event.data);

        if (streamData.stream) {
          setTwitchChannel(streamData.stream);
        }
        if (streamData.events) {
          setEvents(streamData.events);
        }

        if (streamData.fullscreen && streamData.fullscreen === true) {

          setTimeout(() => {
            router.push(`/screen/fullscreen/?channel=${twitchChannel}`);
          }, 0);


        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error parsing JSON:", error);
      }
    });

    eventSource.addEventListener("error", () => {
      eventSource.close();
      setTimeout(() => {
        eventSource =new EventSource("/api/stream");
      }, 1000);
    });
  }, [router, twitchChannel, events]);
```

I have tried multiple things like setting the runtime to edge/node/serverless or removing redis I have tried looking at a bunch of SSE code examples, and it looks quite straight forward, but nothing seems to work or fix the problem.

Has anyone experienced similar issues with SSE in Next.js 14 on Vercel? Any insights or suggestions on how to fix the issue?

Edit:

I could not set i to Edge runtime, as it was to big

Comment: I don't know anything about Vercel, but I had issues making it works for my application as well. The stream was closed automatically after 20 minutes. Apparently it was coming from our HTTP server config (nginx), so maybe you could have a look at yours too (if Vercel give you control on it of course). Here is a SO question that helped me figuring out what was wrong: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27898622/server-sent-events-stopped-work-after-enabling-ssl-on-proxy